# Change tables relations to lowest level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables: `Project, Design, Customer, Contacts`

One project can have multiple designs, each design have customers and that customers have contacts.

In order to retrieve contacts of Projects my team have a table with

```
ProjectKey CustomerKey ContactKey
```

They are primary keys of 3 tables (Project, Customer and Contacts)

So actually this table have a lot of data. Problem is we don't want to relate customers and contacts with Project, we want to relate with Design.

What is the best way to change this relation without affecting actual data? I mean now we want that each Design can have their own contacts and customers, so  I.E one project can have two customers called "Customer 1"  in different designs but they can have different contacts.

Comment: Ignore that last table (which you did not name, making discussion difficult). Always retrieve contacts via the relationships you first describe (project -> design -> customer -> contacts). Effectively your existing table serves no purpose in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options,

First one is to include the DesignKey to your fact table like

`ProjectKey, DesignKey, CustomerKey, ContactKey`

Second One is to have two fact tables

1. `ProjectKey, DesignKey`
2. `DesignKey, CustomerKey, ContactKey`

Option one seems better imo. The important factor is you missed the intermediate level design in your original fact table. It must be included since the contact of a same customer changes upon different designs.